# Configure EC2 to allow others to embed my pages in their websites?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, embed, x-frame-options

I have a domain name with godaddy.com and my code is hosted on AWS.

I need to allow other website to embed some forms or pages on my domain in their websites using Iframe or possible other ways! When I try to use iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/test_em.php" ></iframe>
```

I also have added following line into my php file:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
?>
```

I get the following error:

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values
>   ('SAMEORIGIN, GOFORIT') encountered when loading
>   'https://www.mywebsite.com/test_em.php'. Falling back to 'DENY'.
>
> Refused to display 'https://www.mywebsite.com/test_em.php' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, GOFORIT'.

Please let me know if there is a way to embed my pages somewhere else!

Comment: The error message should make it apparent that something *you* have added to your server is adding the `SAMEORIGIN` header.  AWS does not manipulate your content.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , I don't do that, it seems GOFORIT is not rewrite the X-Frame-Options but append to it!! I believe somewhere in Godaddy or aws there is file that manipulate X-Frame-Options!